# alphabetical array in user given amount of columns

Tags: java, arrays, list, for-loop, multiple-columns

I have this assignment that makes me have to put a set of counties in a user given amount of columns, it doesn't matter about rows, it just needs to be in a certain amount of columns and needs to be in alphabetical order going across [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5Gun.png), i don't understand how to put the list into that user given amount of columns,

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [] counties = {"Arkansas\t", "Ashley\t", "Baxter\t", "Benton\t", "Boone\t", "Bradley\t", "Calhoun\t", 
                "Carroll\t", "Chicot\t", "Clark\t", "Clay\t", "Cleburne\t", "Cleveland", "Columbia\t", "Conway\t", 
                "Craighead", "Crawford\t", "Crittenden", "Cross\t", "Dallas\t", "Desha\t", "Drew\t", "Faulkner\t",
                "Franklin\t", "Fulton\t", "Garland\t", "Grant\t", "Greene\t", "Hempstead", "Hot Spring", "Howard\t",
                "Independence", "Izard\t", "Jackson\t", "Jefferson", "Johnson\t", "Lafayette", "Lawrence\t", "Lee\t",
                "Lincoln\t", "Little River", "Logan\t", "Lonoke\t", "Madison\t", "Marion\t", "Miller\t", "Mississippi",
                "Monroe\t", "Montgomery", "Nevada\t", "Newton\t", "Ouachita\t", "Perry\t", "Phillips\t", "Pike\t",
                "Poinsett\t", "Polk\t", "Pope\t", "Prairie\t", "Pulaski\t", "Randolph\t", "Saline\t", "Scott\t", "Searcy\t",
                "Sebastian", "Sevier\t", "Sharp\t", "St. Francis", "Stone\t", "Union\t", "Van Buren", "Washington",
                "White\t", "Woodruff\t", "Yell"};

        Scanner col = new Scanner(System.in);
        double x = 0;
        x = col.nextInt();
        for(int c = 0; c < counties.length; c++) {  

            for(int p = 0; p < x; p++) {

                System.out.println(counties[c]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no question mark in your post. What is it you're wondering? If you need help with your code, what have you done so far and what's the result of that? Don't expect SO to do the assignment for you.

Comment: What is your question? What part of your assignment do you not understand? Break it into small pieces and solve each of those pieces one at a time. First you need a class with a `main()` method. Do you know how to do that? If not, you should find a Java tutorial that explains how. Then you need to print output. Then you need to loop over each entry in the array and print them out. Then you can worry about formatting it into columns. Each one of these smaller pieces will get you closer to a finished homework assignment.

Comment: i know how to make a main class and all that, i just am not understanding how to put the list of counties in that order and make have the amount of user given columns

Comment: @AlekseiLaek Please show what you have done so far. How do you determine how many columns there should be? The array you show here is already in alphabetic order. So there shouldn't be any problems with the ordering if you just iterate over the array directly.

Comment: @AlekseiLaek, `Arrays.sort(counties)` makes it sorted.  Now all you need to is how you  transform 1D `String[] counties` to 2D `String[][] matrix` array,